# Chrome webdriver (Selenium) halts execution after fetch for a specific element

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, freeze, webdriverwait

Using chromeDriver (84.0.4147.30) in Selenium (with Python), the programs halts when a **specific** element is fetched and wait for user action (e.g, pressing ALT key), keep the execution as if no time has passed (the WebDriverWait doesn't triggers a time exception independently of the passed time).

I have already changed the browser capability (['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'eager'), Expected_Conditions ( *element_to_be_clickable* and *presence_of_element_located* ) without success. I only need to click on a element. Any fetch for it in this point freezes.

It's hard to give you a minimal working example because all of this occurs in a specific and restrict webpage (login is needed and account creation only by administrators). But the initial configuration and the problematic function of my script is given below.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome as Driver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#... more imports*

def strange_correction(): #something useful after login page (without this, the execution freezes) o.O
   browser.refresh()
#... more definitions

pathdriver = "path/to/webdriver"
webmainsource = "https://adress"


TIMEOUT = 20    

nav_options= Options()
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'eager'

browser = Driver(options=nav_options, executable_path=pathdriver, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(webmainsource)

###### Problematic Function (maybe) ######
def wait_for_xpelement(xpath): 

   WebDriverWait(browser, TIMEOUT).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable(( BY.XPATH, xpath )) )
   return WebDriverWait(browser, TIMEOUT).until( EC.presence_of_element_located(( BY.XPATH, xpath )) )
```

Naturally, I have changed *wait_for_xpelement(xpath)* function, sometimes simpler or others more sophisticated. *sleep* functions don't work as well. Anyway, how I can handle with this problem?

Additional Information: Debian 9, Python 3.8

Comment: could you provide an example where you have used this function ? and print. And i think you shouldn't need two WebDriverWait(browser, TIMEOUT).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable(( BY.XPATH, xpath )) ) statements just return statement will do.

Comment: I didn't think it was needed too, but works more stable in this way. The problems occurs in a so private webpage where I work (I'm teacher in a public school. The government has contracted a  web service where the jobs is somewhat stupid in the point of view of user interaction). Sorry but it's hard to me give you a better example. The fact is that a { print("BEGIN") varname.click() print("END") }s hows only one message! If I press ALT,ENTER or even click on the page, I got the second message. The object is effectively clicked.

Anyway, thank you for your intention!